# choose the correct statement regarding $\Bbb R$ with the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

let $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ be  a topological  space   with  the cofinite topology. Every infinite  subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is

choose the correct statement

a) Compact but  not connecetd

b) Both compact and connected

c)Not compact but connected

d) neither compact nor connected

My attempts : i take  $\mathbb{Q}$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then  it is neither  compact not connected so option d)  will correct

is it true ??

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Do you understand what the "cofinite topology" means here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For this problem, you need to depend a lot more on the definitions.  Your intuition regarding the compact/connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ with the *usual* topology is not necessarily applicable.

- In the co-finite topology, a set is closed if and only if it is finite.
- A useful definition of connected is as follows: $A \subset \Bbb R$ will be disconnected (in the cofinite topology) if and only if it can be written as a union $A = B \cup C$, where both $B$ and $C$ are relatively closed.
- Compactness in this context is tricky, but remember the definition: a subset $A$ is compact if and only if every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover.  However: if $\mathcal O = \{U_{\alpha}: \alpha \in I\}$ is an open cover of $A$, then any particular open set $U_{\alpha}$ will exclude at most finitely many elements of $A$.

Comment: thanks  a lots @omnomnomnom,

Comment: @jasmine do you see, then, that the answer is b?

Comment: ya   , i got its @Omnomnomnom    answer is b